# How to format converter parameter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My XAML code is below:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Path=TimeDuration, ConverterParameter='hhmm',
                   Converter={StaticResource HoursMinutesTimeSpanConverter}}"/>
```

Code for converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(String))]
public class HoursMinutesTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>Converts the value into a time only formatted string.</summary>
    /// <param name="value"> The value. </param>
    /// <param name="targetType"> The target type. </param>
    /// <param name="parameter"> The parameter. </param>
    /// <param name="culture"> The culture. </param>
    /// <returns>Time string value. </returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(parameter.ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>Converts the hours minutes string back to
    /// the time span value.</summary>
    /// <param name="value"> The value. </param>
    /// <param name="targetType"> The target type. </param>
    /// <param name="parameter"> The parameter. </param>
    /// <param name="culture"> The culture. </param>
    /// <returns>Time string value. </returns>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return TimeSpan.ParseExact((string)value, parameter.ToString(),
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

It works fine. Actually I need to give this `hh\:mm` as parameter for proper formatting in the converter.

I tried this:

```
>  ConverterParameter='hh{escape character code here}mm' giving codes for the characters
```

**Note** : I typed that way since that's a code in html its not reflecting in my posts so why.

By referring this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115431/wpf-and-string-formatting).

Its not working in my case. How to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code of the converter `HoursMinutesTimeSpanConverter` ?

Comment: `ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"`

Comment: @RahulTripathi Can you please post that complete line of xaml. Because its a ConverterParameter so got confused where to give this code.

Comment: you can use stringFormat instead of the converter.

Comment: Why / what isn't working in your case?

Comment: @Amit It throws error. Xaml error(input string was not in a correct format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that output by using this StringFormat:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TimeDuration,
                StringFormat={}{0:hh}:{0:mm}, FallbackValue=00:00}" />
```

Update :

> **TimeSpan** represents a time interval not a time of day,so it is always
> 24 hrs format & does not have a format for `HH`.
>
> Whereas, with **DateTime** , `hh` will display hours in a 12 hour format
> and you should use `HH` if you want 24 hour format.

Also, the TimeDuration i have considered is of type `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I given HH its not giving results

Comment: @shan I tried with hh, it gives 24  hrs format, I have updated the sentence. D you need 12 hrs format?

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals. For example, "dd.hh:mm" defines a period (.) as the separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator between hours and minutes.

Use like this:

```
Text="{Binding Path=TimeDuration,
                            ConverterParameter='hh\\:mm',
                            Converter={StaticResource HoursMinutesTimeSpanConverter}}
```

This way you'll be able to use whatever separator you like.

*Note*: It is required to escape '\' with a double-slash ('\\') since the `ConverterParameter` value is in "code space" and follows normal C# string literal rules, and not in "markup-space" as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115431/wpf-and-string-formatting) in the question.

Comment: I tried that and its not working. It trows error and xaml page crashes. Did it worked for you?

Comment: If i give the same in C# code 'hh\:mm' in the converter like 
((TimeSpan)value).ToString("hh\:mm") its working.

Comment: I'm not able to test right now, maybe you need double slashes in the markup. I'll validate a bit later.

Comment: Thanks Amit for answering. Yeah i tried with double slashes and it got working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Colons need to be escaped with a backslash i.e.

```
TimeSpan.FromHours(5.25).ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```

Try this:

```
/// <summary>Converts the value into a time only formatted string.</summary>
/// <param name="value"> The value. </param>
/// <param name="targetType"> The target type. </param>
/// <param name="parameter"> The parameter. </param>
/// <param name="culture"> The culture. </param>
/// <returns>Time string value. </returns>
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var escapedFormatString = parameter.replace(@":", @"\:");
    return ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(escapedFormatString);
}
```

and this should work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TimeDuration,
                        ConverterParameter='hh:mm',
                        Converter={StaticResource HoursMinutesTimeSpanConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it.

It should be this way

> ConverterParameter='hh\\:mm'

Two back slashes in the string. And also as Nikita said no need of converters. That approach is fine.